# Query using just the CSV files maintaining foreign key relationship

Tags: python, mysql, csv, python-3.x, pandas

I have a bunch of tables that have been exported as CSV files. They maintain some primary key/foreign key relationships and I would like to make a new CSV file view using these.

The databases/csv:

```
Replys.csv
-PostId
-ReplyId 
-ReplyText

Users.csv
-ReplyId
-UserId
-UserText
```

`ReplyId` is the primary key in `Replys.csv` and a foreign key in `Users.csv`.

> For each `User` find the `ReplyId Users.csv -> Replys.csv ReplyId`.

To print each user, their ReplyId and ReplyText in SQL:

```
SELECT ReplyId, ReplyText
FROM Users, Replys
WHERE Users.ReplyId = Replys.ReplyID
```

How can I do this using just the CSV files?

Comment: I looked for this as well, and decided that, while Pandas supported this in an indirect way, it would be nice to have a dedicated library for defining multi-table schemas that can be used with csv files (or excel sheets ..and even  SQLite and MDB )... so I made a library just for this! I am calling it ticdat and it will be available on PyPi soon. If you'd like to beta test, please let me know!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could perform an `inner` merge:

assuming `replys` is from replys.csv and `users` is from users.csv:

```
replys.merge(users, on='reply_id')
```

for a many to one relationship then you can perform a `left` merge:

```
replys.merge(users, on='reply_id', how='left')
```

There is a useful section in the docs if you're from [SQL](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/comparison_with_sql.html#join)

You'd read the csvs like so:

```
replys = pd.read_csv('Replys.csv')
users = pd.read_csv('Users.csv')
```

The above assumes that the first line in the csvs contain a header line and are comma separated

Answer (score 3):

Pandas dataframes try to give you SQL-like operations. `pd.read_csv` both CSVs, and then do something like `pandas.merge(users, replys, on='reply_id')`.

http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.15.2/merging.html

Answer (score 0):

First off, you would be importing different **tables** into your database, and not multiple databases. This seems to be the first point of confusion. You should be able to import csv-file tables directly into your database. Once you have the described table relationship you should be able to get the necessary data by doing an `INNER JOIN`:

```
# User | ReplyId | ReplyText
SELECT UserId, ReplyId, ReplyText FROM users INNER JOIN Replys USING (ReplyId)
```